# Are monitor drivers necessary?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display

Are drivers for monitors necessary -- in the sense of having tangible need/functionality?

Besides the ability to have Windows label the monitor with its correct name, do the drivers serve a functional purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im sure there are *some* exceptions to this, but monitors (LCDs, CRTs, etc) do not have drivers.  Personally, I have never seen a driver for a monitor.  I have, however, seen `.INF` files for monitors.  INF files are not drivers, but informational files that tell Windows what resolutions, bit depth, refresh rate, etc that the monitor supports.  INF files are not drivers.  Drivers *are* used for graphics cards though.  The reason monitors dont have drivers is that they all conform to the [VESA specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA).  This allows graphics cards to output in a standard format that all monitors understand.

I have seen monitor installer packages labeled as "drivers," however, they just copy INF files - and maybe copy manuals, color profile files,  etc.

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of monitors don't,  unless you're using a touchscreen of course. What's important is your display driver.